# Trouble Hiding Regions When Blocks Are Empty

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

Having trouble seeing why my regions render when I think they shouldn't...

page.html.twig:

```
{% if page.region %}
  {{ page.region }}
{% endif %}
```

region.html.twig:

```
{% if content %}
  <div id="" aria-label="" role="" {{ attributes.addClass(region_classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

block.html.twig:

```
{% if content %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(block_classes) }}>

  {# Label. If not displayed, we still provide it for screen readers. #}
  {% if not configuration.label_display %}
    {% set title_attributes = title_attributes.addClass('visually-hidden') %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_prefix }}
  <h2{{ title_attributes.setAttribute('id', heading_id) }}>{{ configuration.label }}</h2>
  {{ title_suffix }}

  <div>
    {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endif %}
```

block--system-messages-block.html.twig:

```
{% extends "block.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
{{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

I believe it has to do with my extended block templates. These seem to be the ones that will still render even when there is "no" content.

What am I missing? If I use an `if` check around `{% block content %}` Twig throws an exception, inside there is no effect.

Adding `|render|striptags|trim|length > 0` in any of these templates doesn't seem to solve the issue, and in some cases, forms and Drupal messages don't validate (so nothing returns when it should).

Comment: Unsure now as I've set both the Status messages block and Site branding block templates to have the same markup as `block.html.twig` (and don't extend any more) yet have the same results. The Help block, for example, works correctly, but I am not overriding that block with a custom theme template file.

Comment: There is an old issue for D7 https://www.drupal.org/node/953034, still open for D8. In this issue you can find workarounds for blocks depending on the page context, which is mainly the route/path of the page. There isn't a workaround for blocks like the status messages, because this block depends on session data.

Comment: Thanks, @4k4. It's a long thread so maybe missing something. The issue doesn't exist as long as my custom theme uses the stable theme template versions of `region.html.twig` and `block--system-messages-block.html.twig:`. Is that difference part of what the issue thread points to?

Comment: I very much doubt an empty check as proposed in your question or in the issue is possible for a region containing a message block (with any template).